# sound stream stops loading

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a little sound stream script here, but sometimes if you press play to the next track before the current has done loading the next track doesn't comeplete loading

```
package player {
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import player.Loader_bar;

    public class Stream extends Sprite {
        private var _Sound = null;
        private var _Channel = null;

        private var isLoading = false;

        private var _Loader_bar = null;
        public var loader_color = null;
        public var loader_width = 0;
        public var loader_height = 0;

        private var i = 0;

        public function Stream(){
            this._Loader_bar = new Loader_bar();
            addChild(this._Loader_bar);
        }

        public function cnstr(){
            this._Loader_bar.color = this.loader_color;
            this._Loader_bar.w = this.loader_width;
            this._Loader_bar.h = this.loader_height;
            this._Loader_bar.cnstr();
        }

        public function play(url){
            this.stop();
            this.close();

            this._Sound = new Sound();
            this.isLoading = true;

            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, listener_bytesLoaded);
            this._Sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, listener_loadedComplete);

            this._Sound.load(new URLRequest(url));
            this._Channel = this._Sound.play();
        }

        public function stop(){
            if(this._Channel){
                this._Channel.stop();
            }
        }

        private function close(){
            if(this.isLoading){
                this._Sound.close();
            }
        }

        private function listener_loadedComplete(event){
            this.close();

            this.isLoading = false;

            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, listener_bytesLoaded);
        }

        private function listener_bytesLoaded(event){
            var float = this._Sound.bytesLoaded / this._Sound.bytesTotal;
            this._Loader_bar.progress(float);

            var data = {
                i : this.i,
                float : float,
                loaded : this._Sound.bytesLoaded,
                total : this._Sound.bytesTotal
                };
            ExternalInterface.call('swf2js', 'tst_progress', data);
            this.i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close():void
Closes the stream, causing any download of data to cease.

try this:

create a boolean like **hasLoaded**, set it to false.  When the sound successfully loads set it to true.

Then when you play a sound you can test for **hasLoaded** in your **play()** function.  If you have called **play()** before your previous sound has loaded, **hasLoaded** will be false, in which case you call **this._Sound.close()** before creating and loading the new sound.  The reason for testing instead of just calling **close()** is so if you have paused the stream you don't have to reload it to play it again.

ADDITION:

Concerning the load not reporting properly,  you have your progress logic set up incorrectly.  Try this:

1) import flash.events.ProgressEvent

2) For the listener, replace this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, listener_bytesLoaded); in your play() method with this._Sound.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, listener_bytesLoaded);

3) Change your listener_bytesLoaded() method to the following:

```
private function listener_bytesLoaded(event:ProgressEvent)
{
    var percent = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal;
    this._Loader_bar.progress(percent);

    var data = {
            i : this.i,
            float : percent,
            loaded : event.bytesLoaded,
            total : event.bytesTotal
            };

        ExternalInterface.call('swf2js', 'tst_progress', data);
        this.i++;
    }
```

4) Change this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, listener_bytesLoaded);
in your listener_loadedComplete() method to this._Sound.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, listener_bytesLoaded); and then move it out of that method and place it inside the conditional in the close() method.

NOTE - I didn't actually compile this but I think its good to go.  Hope that helps.  :)

Comment: thanks.. now it loads the whole track :) but can you then tell me why already done loaded tracks returns 0 in this._Sound.bytesLoaded ? the loader status gives 0% even if it is done loading (chached).. I have updated my code :)

Comment: I have added edits to my answer concerning your question in the above comment.