# flash music player not playing after second time

Tags: flash-cs5, flash

i am new to flash. i was created flash player for my online radio. it's working fine first two time when i use the stop and play button. the third time it will not playing. i don't know why is not playing , i am using action script 3.0 , my action script is here

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;

// objects

var soundfile:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.xxx.com:80/;stream1.mp3');
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();

// controls 
btnplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playmusic);
btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,stopmusic);
sldVolume.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,changevolume);

function playmusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();
    myMusic.load(soundfile);
    myMusic.play();

}
function changevolume(evt:SliderEvent):void
{
    sTransform.volume = sldVolume.value;
    channel.soundTransform = sTransform;
}

function stopmusic(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    sldVolume.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, changevolume);
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
```

Comment: First of all, you will need to assign something to the soundchannel. a Sound-object play() function will return a SoundChannel: channel = myMysic.play();

Comment: what can i put in soundchannel ?

Comment: myMusic.play() returns a SoundChannel. the channel object you create has no reference to the myMusic object you have, and will in turn do nothing when you set i.e. the volume

Comment: give me some example marijn

Comment: var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest('http://test.tld/my_sound.mp3'));
var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();

Comment: Also, reading this should help:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play()

Comment: still it's not working bro. but if i give single mp3 file it's work fine. only this issue happen when using url radio streaming

Comment: maybe this is helpfull:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827246/sound-stream-stops-loading